# Using fake xhr request with componentWillMount()

Tags: reactjs

'Home' is an intermediate component that redirects based on a xhr response.  I expected 'Home' to display 'Loading ...' as per its render/return, until it receives the xhr response.

But surprisingly,

1) I never see 'Loading ...' at all, but I only see the redirected page.

2) Changing the delay in fake xhr request has no impact, i.e. I still get the response in < 5s

3) Changing `componentWillMount()` to `componentDidMount()` has no impact

4) If I comment out `componentWillMount() { ... }`, then I see 'Loading ...'

Can you please help me understand why ?

xhr.js

```
const myData = {
    getData(cb) {
        setTimeout(cb(true), 25000); // fake async
    }
};

export default myData;
```

Home.js

```
"use strict";

import React from 'react';
import xhr from '../../utils/xhr';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';


class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        const {history} = this.props;
        xhr.getData((flag) => {
            flag ? history.push('/myData') : history.push('/welcome');
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>Loading ...</div>
        );
    }

}

Home.propTypes = {
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withRouter(Home);
```

Comment: if `setTimeout(cb(true), 25000);` would be `setTimeout(() => { cb(true) }, 25000);` does it make any change?

Comment: if you do `setTimeout(cb(true), 25000)` rather than passing setTimeout a function as a parameter you are executing it right away. Its pretty much same sending `cb` to your `getData` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work fine with `componentDidUpdate` except one thing, you didnt run setTimeout correctly

Example:

```js
const getData = cb => {
  setTimeout(() => cb(false), 2500); // fake async
};

class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      pageName: "Loading..."
    };
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    getData(flag => {
      flag
        ? this.setState({ pageName: "myData" })
        : this.setState({ pageName: "wellcome" });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.pageName}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Home />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Update**
As commented below i should explain why and where you should invoke async operations.

- `componentWillMount` - Is almost the same as the `constructor`, it
  runs one time before the component is mounted to the DOM.
  The render method can be invoked before your async operation has finished
  hence it is not ideal to do async operation in this method.   By the
  way, in the [DOCS](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount) its clearly says not to use this method and use
  the `constructor` instead.
- `componentDidMpunt` - Will invoked right after the component is
  mounted to the DOM, this is the ideal method to run async operations.
  Setting the state in this method will trigger a re-render (which
  exactly what happens in the example above) [DOCS](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount).

Comment: I think adding little more explanation about why `DidMount` should be used against `WillMount`, will really help OP to understand the behaviour of lifecycle methods.

Comment: plus one for that @RaghavGarg i will update my answer